# JS won't send the user to a subpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to send the user to a subpage on my website using js since it needs if/else statements. The js can send the user to youtube, twitter and other websites but it can't send the user to my subpage.. Please help

Here is the JS:

```
function myFormSubmit() {
  myInput = document.getElementById('number');
  
  if(myInput.value == 1) {
    window.location.href = 'https://csgotradeup.org/tradeups/9324ec1'
    alert(1);
  }
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="Searchbox">
  <form onsubmit="myFormSubmit()">
    <input type="number" class="input" placeholder="What is your budget?" min="0" id="number"
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What happens when you press the link? Your code looks somewhat correct by syntax, so I suspect it has something to do with either your server or other parts of the code that handle that subpage

Comment: On the website you are given a search box and you need to put in a number into that searchbox. I then want to use whatever the user inputs to send the user to a certain subpage. But now what happens is that when I type a certain number and submit it nothing happens except for an alert of 1 which is said in the code. It works when sending the user to the same specified subpage through HTML href which shows that the subpage isn't broken.

Comment: your code should work even when you have mentioned that other websites are working so I am sure your code is right, are you sure everything else is fine with your code? in the browser developer tools, console tab try window.location.href = 'https://csgotradeup.org/tradeups/9324ec1' to see if it is working or not.

Comment: Trying that didn't work but " window.location.href = '/tradeups/9324ec1' " worked.